# New threads vs. reusing threads

Tags: java, multithreading

We have a desktop application that has some background threads and, because of execution of external commands, also needs threads for handling the out and err streams.

We could either create new threads and let them finish or we could reuse threads. Would reusing threads have some benefit, e.g. in case of performance or memory usage?

Comment: Define "reusing" threads. A thread can be started only once.

Comment: Thread sharing kind of reuses Thread. Thread Pool is good option to look at.

Comment: A thread can not be re-started/re-run. So, creating a new thread is only option. Thread pool eases your task by creating a new thread when a thread's execution is finished.

Comment: @GauravGupta I don't believe that is true. Although a thread can't be re-run it can endlessly poll a queue and pull tasks from it; Effectively never ending. I believe thread pools act in this way. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) *"Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. .... **If** any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks."*

Comment: @UmNyobe: why exactly?

Comment: @Because it already does what you are want to do **AND** is available in the standard java library

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to reuse a `Thread` because `Thread` once finishes (exit the `run()` method) its `Thread.State` passes from `Thread.State.RUNNABLE` to `Thread.State.TERMINATED` and the Thread class does not have a `setState(Thread.State)` method for setting its state to reuse it.

However we can take help of **Thread Pooling** in Java. In case of thread pool, a group of fixed size threads are created. A thread from the thread pool is pulled out and assigned a job by the service provider. After completion of the job, thread is contained in the thread pool again.

Advantage of Thread Pooling :

1. Thread pooling saves the virtual machine the work of creating brand new threads for every short-lived task.
2. It minimizes overhead associated with getting a thread started and cleaning it up after it dies
3. By creating a pool of threads, a single thread from the pool can be recycled over and over for different tasks.
4. Reduce response time because a thread is already constructed and started and is simply waiting for its next task

Comment: How the thread pool can reuse thread? Why state of thread in thread pool does not change to TERMINATED after the run method exit?

Comment: I have the same question as of @MinhTriLe

Comment: Because the thread you use in a thread pool has code that runs a runnable, catching potential exceptions, and if done, waits for the next runnable to run.

Comment: Thread pool can reuse thread because threads in thread pool are never completed its task, they run a piece of code that pull job from job queue and run it. If their is no job in queue, thread will run a for loop to waiting for job to come in queue.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 1.5 and above, you should try not to create Thread as much as possible.

Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html. Try to use Thread pool executor.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing a thread has the following advantage:

- no new object needs to be created (thread object)
- lower latency because the task can be picked up by an existing idle thread
- no old object needs to be garbage collected
- using a pool also introduces a limit to concurrently running threads (averages out load spikes)

Comment: Is creating a thread object significantly more expensive than creating a plain object?

Comment: if by plain object you mean "new Object()" then yes - just look at the constructor of the Thread class to get an impression of what is going on when creating a new thread